# How to create a custom textbox with a label and value?

Tags: javascript, html, css, textbox, label

I am not a designer but I am with a task to implement a functionality. I have to develop a working UI where a user can enter values in text box inside grid. While entering these values the user should have reference to a value which is different for each textbox in a grid. I therefore want to design a textbox where the user while entering the values gets to see the reference value then and there. can anyone suggest me a good design to solve this problem.

What I have thought of is that having a custom textbox with a part of left top of textbox as a uneditable label while the other area of textbox is editable to enter values.

[image]

so as seen in image , the top left is where I will show the value to be referred , while the white space is a textbox for user to enter the values.

If the proposed solution by me is a good one then how do I implement it? or any other solution anyone can suggest?

Comment: Do you use any javascript framework?

Comment: jquery is what I use, I can use what is required

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 methods.

1. You can use the reference label in `absolute` position and place it on the textbox with an equal amount of padding ( width of the reference label ) from the left.
2. You can use `:before` tag and apply it directly to the textbox. Give `:before` tag position `absolute` and textbox position `relative`.

Comment: will try and revert in 10 minutes

Comment: Something like this. only you can remove the appearance on focus and make label visible all the time
https://css-tricks.com/float-labels-css/

Comment: looks good , but how can I also have a reason box to compare two values and force the user to enter a reason if the values are not equal?   what I want to achieve is http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/103758/how-to-create-a-custom-textbox-with-a-label-and-value

Comment: you can use Jquery to check the value and compare it with the value of lable. if value is not equal add a class to the parent div and make the color red. and u can use something like this https://vitalets.github.io/x-editable/  for user to enter reason